# Why does Linux need cvs for ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, debian

I just set up a new Debian 10 system today.  I was able to ssh in, then, when I thought I had all my config stuff setup, I rebooted to be sure it as all sticking and I had done it right.  Then I tried to ssh to it from my iMac:

```
[hal@sirhokus:~]$ ssh aule
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
bash: cvs: command not found
Connection to aule closed.
```

(Note I'm using an authorized key so I don't have to type in my password.)

I tried it from a Linux system on my LAN:

```
[hal@brandyhall:~]$ ssh aule
hal@aule's password: 
bash: cvs: command not found
Connection to aule closed.
[hal@brandyhall:~]$
```

And I even tried it from the new system, using ssh to log into my own account and the same thing happened.

When I grep .bashrc on the target system, I get nothing.  I renamed ~/.bashrc to .bashrc-bak to test it and got the same thing.

So no matter what machine I use to ssh to this Debian system, it appears to log in, complain it can't find the command cvs, then logs me out.  This happens even with no .bashrc on the target machine.

Of course I want to fix it, but why is the target system seemingly trying to execute cvs?

(This is a stock Debian 10 install, with KDE added.  I have not set up any servers on it.  Other than me trying to add a .bashrc to the system and editing /etc/ssh/sshd_config, the system is virginal.)

Comment: My guess is you made a typo while editing a file, or copy-pasted something irrelevant. Check your `sshd_config`, your `authorized_keys` and any other file you edited. `grep -ri cvs $HOME /etc` may reveal something. You may also want to check logs (`/var/log/auth.log` comes to mind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[hal@sirhokus:~]$ ssh aule
Warning: No xauth data; using fake authentication data for X11 forwarding.
bash: cvs: command not found
Connection to aule closed.
```

It appears that the remote system is configured to run `cvs` when you log in. It looks like you're authenticating with an SSH key? It seems likely to be one of these things:

1. You are subject to a "forced command" on the remote system, possibly associated with the ssh key that you are using. Basically, the remote ssh server may be configured to run `cvs` when you log in with that key. See [here](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd#AUTHORIZED_KEYS_FILE_FORMAT) and [here](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd#command=_command_) for how this can be configured through your `authorized_keys` file on the server.
2. Your `.bash_profile`, `.bashrc`, or similar shell startup script is invoking cvs.
3. Your account on the remote system is configured with a special shell that runs cvs. Your "login shell" might be a shell script, for example.

Comment: That's it - I had apparently deleted a '#' from sshd_config and it was trying to execute cvs, according to an example command on the last line in there.  It was given as an example forced command and I must have accidentally deleted that one character from the file.